# Create WS-security header in Groovy

Tags: web-services, soap, groovy

I have to create UsernameToken section in SOAP header using Groovy but i can't find how to do it. I look at WSLite but how I understood this lib cant work with WSS header. I need something like this

```
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
            <wsse:Username>testuser</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">******</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">/KRqhWHKnB66WVTgZ4GBVg==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2019-02-25T12:50:36.307Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided to use spring ws template

```
compile "org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-security"
```

and it helped me

```
def WebServiceTemplate createWsTemplate(String url, String login, String password) {

Wss4jSecurityInterceptor wss4jSecurityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor()
wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementActions(WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN)
wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementUsername(login)
wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword(password)
wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementPasswordType("PasswordText")
wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementUsernameTokenCreated(true)
wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementUsernameTokenNonce(true)

SaajSoapMessageFactory msgFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory(MessageFactory.newInstance())
msgFactory.afterPropertiesSet()
WebServiceTemplate wsTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate(msgFactory)
wsTemplate.setInterceptors(wss4jSecurityInterceptor)
wsTemplate.setDefaultUri(url)
wsTemplate.afterPropertiesSet()
wsTemplate.setMessageSender(sender)

return wsTemplate }
```